# How to see include existing repository in smartSvn?

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I checkout svn repository with a line command, so how to see in the source tree of smartSVN?

I don't know if it should be "open working copy" or "import into repository"

Answer (score 0):

It was "open working copy" and select my repository directory